# What does the "@" sign in jQuery selector means?

Tags: jquery

What does the `@` sign in the following code means ?

```
$("input[@type=checkbox][@checked]").each(
    function() {
        ...
    }
);
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is an xpath convention for [attribute selection](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/), which was discontinued two versions ago.
You should remove the `@` sign if you want the selectors to work on the current version.

Alternatively, the selector `$("input:checkbox:checked")` should work just the same.

Comment: Instead of finding that question asked a couple weeks back which this is a dupe of I'm just gonna upvote you since symbols are such a pain to search for anyway :)

Comment: Here's a good mnemonic: "@" = "at" => "at-tribute" => "@-tribute"