# Jquery selector not working: Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: a[@href]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<body>
    <div>
        <p>This is <strong>first</strong> paragraph</p>
        <p>And this one is second</p>
        <span><h2>I am p inside span</h2></span>
        <h1>I am h1</h1>
    </div>
    <div name="divName">
        <p><a href="www.google.pl">This is a paragraph in second div</a></p>
    </div>
</body>
```

The following code gives me:

> Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: a[@href]

```
 //Another file
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("div[p]").css("background-color", "green");
    $("a[@href]").css("background-color", "yellow");
 });
```

Also the `$("div[p]").css("background-color", "green");` seems to be doing nothing.
What's going on here?
According to http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/jquery-selectors.htm these should be valid.

Comment: why not assign classes to elements `p` and `a` and directly bind them with jQuery

Comment: posted an answer below but I don't understand what do you need to do with the link...

Comment: @Shehary The problem is that the syntax should work according to: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/jquery-selectors.htm

Comment: I've been using jQuery for a long time and have never seen selectors like `div[p]` before. I'm not even sure how to interpret that. It seems to imply an object literal, or that `p` is an attribute. Methinks you've been led astray by that site.

Comment: And the `@` in  `a[@href]` implies an exact match, which means you'd have to include a value for the attribute. `a[@href="someval"]`

Comment: why don't you consult the actual [jquery docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)?

Comment: Also the `@`-prefixed attribute-selectors were - as I recall - deprecated in jQuery back in version 1.3 or 1.4; an absolute aeon ago in computer/internet time.

Comment: @isherwood `a[href]` is fairly standard/frequently used, not `a[@href]` though - that was removed about 10 years old (I found a question on this from 2010)

Comment: @user3142434, this tutorials is too old and most of the information on it is invalid you shouldn't follow these tutorials, jQuery has it's own site where you can find detail of each function in detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what version of jquery the 'tutorialspoint' is using, but, assuming your referring to number 17:

> $("div[p]")
>
> Selects all elements matched by  that contain an element matched by `<p>`

This is either simply wrong or very out-dated (Edit: looks like it's about 10 years out of date... see edit below).

There are also many questions on SO that ask how to achieve exactly this and none of them give this answer.

The page you should be referring to is:

https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Which shows that `[]` is used to match attributes, eg:

```
<p data-id='123'>
$("p[data-id]")
```

will match all `p` that have attribute `data-id` (regardless of value in this case).

---

*Edit*: To address the specific question in the title "unrecognised expresion a[@href]" - see this question: [What does the "@" sign in jQuery selector means?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879109/what-does-the-sign-in-jquery-selector-means) the answer for which states that this was **obsolete "2 versions ago" in *2010***

So I'm guessing your tutorial page is about *10 years out of date*

Answer (score 1):

```
<div>
        <p>This is <strong>first</strong> paragraph</p>
        <p>And this one is second</p>
        <span><h2>I am p inside span</h2></span>
        <h1>I am h1</h1>
    </div>
    <div name="divName">
        <p><a href="www.google.pl">This is a paragraph in second div</a></p>
    </div>
```

JS

```
//Another file
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("div p").css("background-color", "green");
    $("a[href]").css("background-color", "yellow");
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/leojavier/kkj5c267/1/

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/jquery-selectors.htm Check this out. The $("div[p]").css("background-color", "green"); should work as well